# Visual Studio 2010 default property sheets seem linked under both debug and release configurations, what's up?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm trying to alter the default property sheet on a new install of Visual Studio 2010 for C++ projects. Just trying to add a few directories (for Boost etc.) and optimisation settings for release builds, basic stuff like that. Obviously there are some settings that I want to be different for different configurations. Problem is that whatever I try from the property manager window of my project, everything I do seems to affect both configurations.

I tried multi-selecting both -> right click -> properties initially, to set up common settings, and that did exactly the same thing as selecting Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.User under either debug or release. So everything affects both configs.

Now, as I understand it, Microsoft.Cpp.Win32... is a single file (at least, a single file for x86 configs, single file for x64 etc.) so the fact that I can't change the configs individually actually makes some degree of sense. But if I can't do it that way, how can I do it?

Appreciate any advice!

Comment: When you right-click a property sheet + Properties then you'll see that both the Configuration and Platform comboboxes at the top of the window are disabled.  In other words, you need a separate property sheet for settings that are sensitive to the Configuration.  I typically name them "Foo.Debug" and "Foo.Release".

Comment: @HansPassant Okay, thanks! Is there a simple way to make those sheets default in new projects though?

Comment: That requires a project template.  VS2012 supports that, 2010 not yet.

Comment: Thanks again. The other thing I'm confused about is that when you open the properties for Microsoft.Cpp... under, say, debug, a different set of properties is listed than for release, implying that further up the food chain this user sheet is inheriting its properties from some source which *does* differentiate between the 2 configurations. Is this true and is it possible for me, as a user, to interfere further up?

Comment: I don't see that.  The file itself doesn't have any Condition selectors in it that test the $(Configuration).  Editing the file by hand probably works.

Comment: Regarding the different set of properties for debug and release see the "Conditional Properties" section of this blog post: [Sharing project properties in Visual C++](http://manski.net/2012/01/11/sharing-project-properties-in-visual-c/#conditional-properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. See comment discussion under question.